# Camunda ProcessDefinition not available after deployment

Tags: java, deployment, bpmn, camunda

I have a Camunda 7.3 standalone h2-in-mem configuration which I want to integrate into my own application. When I create a deployment based on a (valid) bpmn xml String, I get no process definition in return:

```
public String deployProcess(WorkflowDef workflowDef) throws IOException, SQLException {
    //prepare resources
    String name = workflowDef.getTitle()+".bpmn";
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(workflowDef.getBpmnXml().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));

    //prepare deployment
    RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
    final DeploymentBuilder deploymentBuilder = repositoryService.createDeployment();
    deploymentBuilder.name(workflowDef.getId());
    DeploymentEntity deploymentResult;

    try {
        deploymentResult = (DeploymentEntity) repositoryService.createDeployment().addInputStream(name, stream).deploy();
    } finally {
        stream.close();
    }

    //read the result
    String deploymentId = deploymentResult.getId();
    ProcessDefinition processDef = repositoryService.createProcessDefinitionQuery().deploymentId(deploymentId).singleResult();

    //return the process definition id for later query
    String processDefinitionId = processDef.getId();
    return processDefinitionId;
}
```

*Note:* The object workflowDef is just a wrapper, which contains definitions from the bpmn.io modeler, like name and the bpmn XML as String. I also make sure, that engine and db are initialized and running.

After deploying, I get a NullPointerException at the line

```
String processDefinitionId = processDef.getId();
```

Even when I try to get the definition via

```
repositoryService.createProcessDefinitionQuery().list();
```

I just receive an empty list. Is there a misconception in my code?

Comment: Is your process marked as executable? Check the Executable checkbox in the modeler or the isExecutable attribute of the process element in the BPMN XML. If so is there any log output of the engine during deployment?

Comment: Can you check your database and see if the process is there?

Comment: It works now. I do use the bpmn.io javascript modeler where isExecutable is of course false by default so I had to implement an option to set this flag first. Now it runs fine!

Comment: @Lista after setting the executable flag it is also listed in the Db.